# Cycles Render Engine gives result look weird, missing light and reflection

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have problem with cycles rendering, the left image is my rendering, I have checked render settings and image settings that everything is fine, but still get this problem though I created a new blender file and imported them into new blender file.

Hope everyone can help me fix this problem, this project from my work at company for product modeling

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: It looks like there is a light in the viewport render preview that doesn't seem to be in the actual render on the left when comparing the arc in the background and the ground plane. But the _Outliner_ doesn't show any light visible in viewport but disabled in render... so it's hard to tell from the screenshot what is going on there.

Comment: You say the left image is your render, and your complaint is ( maybe? ) that it isn't the same as the right image. But you haven't told us what the right image  _is_.  (For one thing, there's a light visible in the right image, that isn't in the left image..) Please explain what the right image is, and why you expect the left image to be the same.